# $f(x)=2^x$. $x \in [0,10]$ Darboux sums

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Dividing given interval onto $n$ equal parts find Darboux upper and lower sums.

$f(x)=2^x$.  $x \in [0,10]$

$L(f,P)$ = $\frac{10}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^\frac{10(i-1)}{n}$

$U(f,P)$ = $\frac{10}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^\frac{10i}{n}$

I can't continue from here,I don't think I did something wrong.

Comment: Sum of geometric series formula?

Answer (score 1):

Although the "right way" is to use the [Geometric Series Formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/geometric-progressions/), you actually can argue even without that.

Just note that
$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\frac{10}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^\frac{10i}{n}-\frac{10}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^\frac{10(i-1)}{n}$$
which means
$$U(f,P)-L(f,P)=\frac{10}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^\frac{10i}{n}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^\frac{10(i-1)}{n}\right)$$

I'll leave it to you to find out which terms will get cancelled, which ones will remain, and what will happen to the remaining terms when you take $\lim_{n\to \infty}$. If you can't figure it out, do tell me and I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: It becomes $\frac{10}{n}(1-2^{10})$ ?

Comment: @unit1991 so what happens when $\lim_{n\to \infty}$

Comment: Yep it converges to $0$.Because it converges to $0$ we can integrate it. But my question was to only find upper and lower sums

Comment: @unit1991 oops! I didn't see that :|   Can you use the gp formula (the link to which is given in my answer)? Try using it. If you can't I'll help you.

Comment: Thank you very much I already did it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my way is right. We use the formula for the geometric series and the definition of the integral.

First we have to split $I=[a,b]$. We use $x_k=a+\frac{b-a}{n+1}k$. For our problem: $x_k=\frac{10}{n+1}k$. Now we put this $x_k$ into our function $f(x)=2^x \Rightarrow f(x_k)=2^{\frac{10}{n+1}k}$. Using the definition of darboux-sums we find:
$$L=\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{\frac{10}{n+1}k}\cdot \frac{10}{n+1}=\frac{10}{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n 2^{(\frac{10}{n+1})^k}$$
Now we can use the formula for the geometric series: $\sum_{k=0}^n q^k=\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q} $ with $q=2^{\frac{10}{n+1}}$

$$...=\frac{10}{n+1}\left(\frac{1-\left(2^\frac{10}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{1-2^\frac{10}{n+1}} \right)=\frac{10}{n+1}\left(\frac{1-2^{10}}{1-2^{\frac{10}{n+1}}} \right):= s_n$$

The last step ist to evaluate the limit when $n \to \infty$. So we finaly get $$\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n=\frac{1023}{\log(2)}\approx 1475,87703 $$

Comment: U(f,P) is your job :D